# Google Drive Api batching - getting the result of mulitple file uploads

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-python-api

This question is formulated on the basis of python, but the core issue concerns Drive API in general.

I have the following python code for uploading multiple files deploying batching:

```
batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=f_delete_file_batch_callback)
for item in files_list:
    filename = item.name
    file_metadata = {'title' : filename}
    fo = open(filename, "w+b")
    fo.write(item.file.read())
    media = MediaFileUpload(...)
    batch.add(service.files().insert(body=file_metadata, media_body=media))                              

http =  credential.authorize(httplib2.Http())
batch.execute(http = http)
uploaded_files = ... # Here's the question. How do I get new files?
return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'files': uploaded_files}
```

The problem is that I don't understand how I could fetch the newly uploaded files so that I could pass the new lines to ajax and render them on client-side:

my_template.html:

```
{% for item in files.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>{{item.modifiedDate}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

javascript:

```
$.post(url, data, function(){
    $table.append(response)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From memory, the response from the batch request is an array of file resources for the newly created files. Actually it's a multipart mimetype with a part for each component request.

Poking around the python library (ugh I hate libraries), it looks like there is an optional callback to the constructor that is called for each body part. In your case you've defined this as `callback=f_delete_file_batch_callback`

Soooo, I would expect this callback to be called with a file object for each inserted file.

By default, the file object will only contain title, id and mimetype. If you want the modifiedDate, you'll need to add that (or *) to the `fields` parameter.

Comment: Have you tested it? In my app, it returns None. Do you use v2 or v3?

Comment: It hasn't changed between v2 and v3. Here is the documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch which confirms "The server's response is a single standard HTTP response with a multipart/mixed content type; each part is the response to one of the requests in the batched request, in the same order as the requests." 

What the python library does with that is anybody's guess. You may need to look at the source code to figure it out. This is why I advise against using libraries - they cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: you could post your question at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-api-python-client . That way the library authors should see it.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of doing this without library? The doc is very obscure on this